# Project organization in Xcode4

Tags: ios, xcode4

How do you organize your Xcode4 projects?

1. With reference to groups/directories
   in Xcode vs. on Disk
2. With reference
   to SCM (I'm using Subversion for my
   projects)

I'm looking for something similar to [this](http://akosma.com/2009/07/28/code-organization-in-xcode-projects/) (which is for Xcode3).

Comment: Actually you can take the information from your link and go ahead using the same approach on Xcdoe4 projects. There is not big difference when it comes to disk location and SCM. Besides this I more prefer a module-wise organisation (so Controller, View, Model classes used within the Controller all go into one subdir)

Comment: I'm trying to use the same approach, but i'm running into problems with subversion. Subversion doesn't recognize that some files have been introduced, and should be added/committed to the repository. I'm basically running into different Xcode4 issues. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marking marcus's comment as the answer:

> Actually you can take the information from your link and go ahead
>   using the same approach on Xcdoe4 projects. There is not big
>   difference when it comes to disk location and SCM. Besides this I more
>   prefer a module-wise organisation (so Controller, View, Model classes
>   used within the Controller all go into one subdir)